# Update a mysql table with another

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, inner-join, insert-into

I just want to copy only the values that don't match from table2 (tpl2) to tpl1. What is the right syntax to do it? I use "update inner join" but deletes values from tpl1. Should i use insert select instead? See bellow:

```
tpl1       tpl2             tpl1
------    -------          -------
col_1      col_1           col_1
1           1       --->     1
2           2                2
3           3                3
4           4                4
            5                5
            6                6
            7                7
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use INSERT IGNORE.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tpl1 SELECT * FROM tpl2;
```

This means that when the insert attempts to copy a given row from tpl2 to tpl1, and the row already exists (that is, the new row would conflict with an existing PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY value), then it just skips that row.

Comment: +1 for **easy and quickly** to understand for your query, i like it @Bill

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into tpl1(col1)
    select col_1
    from tpl2
    where not exists (select 1 from tpl1 where tpl1.col_1 = tpl2.col2);
```

If you want to prevent duplicates, you might also consider this approach.  Create a unique index or constraint on `tpl1(col_1)`:

```
create unique index tpl1(col_1);
```

Then simply ignore any values that already exist.  This method of ignoring using `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into tpl1(col_1)
    select col_1
    from tpl2
    on duplicate key update col_1 = tpl1.col_1;
```

The assignment does not change the table, so the result is that duplicates are ignored.

Comment: i think your update query is wrong, she (@user3247935) don't want to display output like your code, you should must see the output in this post[question]. And your output is like as (**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a5b/1**), and she want the output like in @Bill code(**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf3bd/1**)...

Comment: @jmail . . . You didn't add the unique index on `tbl1`.  That is an important part of the solution.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85fe8.)  This approach is pretty much the same as Bill's approach *except* it is specific about the errors being ignored.  And, I was a minute earlier ;).

Comment: I've try `without unique index`.. but no use, nothing has change in the output...

Comment: @jmail . . . I have no idea what your last comment refers to.  My SQL Fiddle link works correctly and follows the answer.  You need the unique index on the right field.

Comment: your link nothing has been displayed, it empty page like there have no code.   (sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85fe8.)

Comment: @jmail . . . I'm not sure why that would happen.  Try:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02652/1.  Or just add `create unique index t1_fn on t1(fn)` as specified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by left joining tpl1 to tpl2 and only inserting values that don't exist in tpl1

```
insert into tpl1 (col_1)
   select a.col_1 
   from tpl2 a
      left join tpl1 b using (col_1)
   where 
      b.col_1 is null;
```